# How to create an array for simple product sku and if variation product variation sku and parent sku

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello I need to create an array that if the product is simple, product sku.  If the product is a variation, variation sku and parent product sku.  It doesn't seem to be clearing the "is_type('variable') check and just put the product id sku for both itemID and itemGroupID.  Please see my code:

```
          if (!class_exists('WooCommerce')) return;
            $cartRecordsJM = [];
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    // get the data of the cart item
   $product = $cart_item['data'];
   // Only for variable products when cart is not empty
    if( $product->is_type('variable') && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
 { 
    $variation_id = WC_Product($cart_item['variation_id']);
    $product_id         = $variation_id->get_sku();
    $parent = WC_Product($product['product_id']);
    $parent_id       = $parent->get_sku();
  } elseif (! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
    $simple_id = new WC_Product($cart_item['product_id']);
    $product_id = $simple_id->get_sku();
    $parent_id = '';
  } else {
    return;
  }
    
    $cartRecordsJM[] = [
     'itemID'=> $product_id, 
     'itemGroupID'=> $parent_id 
   ];
      }
?>
```

I am then passing the array in javascript

```
var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($cartRecordsJM); ?>;
        var cartRecords = [];
        var length = jArray.length;
        // Repeat this block for each item the customer has in their cart
        for (let i = 0; i < length;  i++) {
        cartRecords.push({'itemId': jArray[i]['itemID'] ,'itemGroupId': jArray[i]['itemID']});
}
        var page_meta = {
            'pageType': "cart",
            'cartRecords': cartRecords
        };
```

What i am trying to do is create an array of all items in the cart that looks like the following:

```
cartRecords: Array(5)
0: {itemId: "simple/variation sku", itemGroupId: "parent product sku if variation"}
1: {itemId: "simple/variation sku", itemGroupId: "parent product sku if variation"}
2: {itemId: "simple/variation sku", itemGroupId: "parent product sku if variation"}
3: {itemId: "simple/variation sku", itemGroupId: "parent product sku if variation"}
4: {itemId: "simple/variation sku", itemGroupId: "parent product sku if variation"}
5: {itemId: "simple/variation sku", itemGroupId: "parent product sku if variation"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a silly mistake, I actually had it correct before all of my edits.  I made the mistake of putting

```
cartRecords.push({'itemId': jArray[i]['itemID'] ,'itemGroupId': jArray[i]['itemID']});
```

"itemID" in both locations...

Here is the correct way to accomplish this, tested and works!

```
if (page_type == 'cart') {
        <?php
          if (!class_exists('WooCommerce')) {return; }// add this line 
            $cartRecordsJM = [];
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    // get the data of the cart item
   $product = $cart_item['data'];
   // ONLY SIMPLE PRODUCT
    if( $product->is_type('simple') ) { 
    $simple_id = new WC_Product($cart_item['product_id']);
    $product_id = $simple_id->get_sku();
    $parent_id = '';
  } elseif ( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ) {
    $variation_jm = new WC_Product_Variation($cart_item['variation_id']);
    $product_id = $variation_jm->get_sku();
    $parent = wc_get_product($variation_jm->get_parent_id());
    $parent_id       = $parent->get_sku();
  } 
    
    $cartRecordsJM[] = [
     'itemID'=> $product_id, 
     'itemGroupID'=> $parent_id 
   ];
      }
?>
        var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($cartRecordsJM); ?>;
        var cartRecords = [];
        var length = jArray.length;
        // Repeat this block for each item the customer has in their cart
        for (let i = 0; i < length;  i++) {
        cartRecords.push({'itemId': jArray[i]['itemID'] ,'itemGroupId': jArray[i]['itemGroupID']});
}
        var page_meta = {
            'pageType': "cart",
            'cartRecords': cartRecords
        };
        console.log(page_meta);
    }
```